# SQL Server : make use of foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables `Product` and `Vendors`. In my `Product` table, I have a primary key and one foreign key `VendorID` which references the primary key of the `Vendors` table:

[image]

[image]

So, what I was trying to do is to determine which products have a quantity of less than 1000 then display the product's vendor ID and name.

I tried doing this:

```
SELECT VendorID, Name
FROM Vendors, Product
WHERE Quantity < 1000;
```

but I get an error

> Ambiguous column name 'VendorID'

This is the only solution I can think of since I am just only a beginner in using SQL

I think the output must go like this

```
VendorID    Name
--------------------------------------------
V00002      Liwayway Marketing Corporation 8
V00003      Monde Nissin
```

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Where is join condition? And use tableName.columnName to avoid ambiguity

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I respectfully suggest you study up on [JOIN](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/) and then try again.

Comment: With due all respect sirs, I think I've clearly said that I am just NEW in doing SQL Database and sorry if I don't know some syntax that you guys know already.

Comment: you are getting error `ambiguous column name 'VendorID'` because when trying to execute your select statement it does not from which table to pick column `VendorID`  because both the tables have this column. so SQL planner is confused and gave you error. so always when you join multiple tables and they happen to have the same field name you need to tell which table along with it. i would recommend to refer "aliases" and joins. thx

Comment: @simpleApp thanks for some information, I'll try to use the `JOIN` Syntax.

Comment: *"I think I've clearly said that I am just NEW in doing SQL Database"* which makes it even more confusing as to why you chose to use syntax from the 1980's when it was superseded in 1992. If you're new make sure you're looking at tutorials and articles that are recent, not text books from the mid 90's when the old ANSI-89 implicit syntax was still actively used and the ANSI-92 syntax hadn't been fully adopted. SQL, and T-SQL, has changed a lot over the last decade, let alone the last 30 years, so make sure you're reading about the current state of the language/dialect.

Comment: And as per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @Testtest just to clarify some of the above responses; the purpose of this site is to answer specific technical issues you encounter while attempting to solve your problem. What this site is not, is a tutorial or learning site. So really you are going to be better off finding some tutorials and learning material that match your ability, and then post a question here if you don't understand something specific you come across. And if using SQL Server then the official documentation is very good with lots of good examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
USE myDB;

SELECT v.VendorID, v.Name
FROM Vendors v JOIN Product p
ON v.VendorID = p.VendorID
WHERE p.Quantity < 1000;
```

Comment: It works thanks for this, but may I ask? What is `vendors v` and `product p` are those variables to be use?

Comment: `v` and `p` are just for aliasing the table name. for more check this out:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL)

Comment: I'm a bit confuse about `ON` how does that exactly works?

Comment: @Testtest `ON` clause allows you to specify the column names for join keys in both tables.

Answer (score -1):

It is happening because your program doesn't know which Vendors or Product table to choose from.

I would try to make a union, like NATURAL JOIN which will make your tables "combine", else, you will get every row of Vendors paired with every row of Product.

Plus: the tables are different, so you have to "pair" them so you can use attributes from the two of them.